# How do I display one web page inside another and let it "overlay" other page elements?

Tags: html, css

What I really want to do is have a simple html-only (css, perhaps, but no javascript, php, etc) menu-bar that I can update once and all pages automatically get the new form, no matter how old, etc.

I've easily done this by using html with CSS. I've created a tiny "web page" that's basically only the menu bar and then display it on other pages by placing the following where I want the bar to appear:

```
<object data=menu.html width=100%>
<embed src="menu.html"></embed>
ERROR: Unable to display menu bar!
</object>
```

Works great! Only one problem: It introduces scroll bars and such instead of just overlaying the content of the page already displayed. Booo!

Figuring I CANNOT be alone in wanting this, I've tried adding various css syntax like:

```
"style=overflow: visible;"
```

to try and overcome this, but it never works. I've looked at the documentation hoping this has been added... Seems like it SHOULD be a simple addition to the existing model of the web page world! Say, you'd give your window a height, and that part is displayed like a portal, and any "overflow" is allowed to be visible without scroll bars! Duh! But, I guess I'm alone in wanting that.

Or, not quite, as pointed out in a comment below, there's also iframe. So, I tried it:

```
<iframe src="menu.html" height=45px width=100% frameborder=0
scrolling=no style="overflow: visible;">
<p>Oops! Your browser does not support iframes.</p></iframe>
```

This fails in exactly the same was as with "object" above.

As an alternative, I was thinking of maybe tiling my pages anyway, by making a grid view. But it's not at all clear to me that this is a route to success.

*Other than going with a solution* [like those suggested here,](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4607136/creating-reusable-html-for-navigation-bar-on-multiple-pages) what other alternatives can get this working for me?

Do note that there are many good reasons to avoid those suggestions, though I'm prepared to agree there are many good reasons to go with those solutions, too.

Comment: I think you mean to use an iframe tag, not object/embed.

Comment: @MatthewLevy Actually, I would if it worked! It has the exact same problem / behavior as object / embed, at least in this instance. ...The documentation CLAIMS it will support style but, at least on my version of Firefox, the style "overflow: visible;" doesn't work.

Comment: True iframe doesn't have an "overflow:visible" concept. But you can set the height and width properties (which I assume you know given your use case). You can also set the frameborder property to 0. I second @BWilson though - you are trying to do something that pretty much violates web application design principles.

Comment: @MatthewLevy Actually, it doesn't. And, it's arrogant to say so, not that I've actually taken offense; most programmers are very arrogant.  Given my great many years in the computer world, it's pretty clear to me that http / html was incompetently designed from the start, and the only reason the web is successful is because of the billions upon billions of compute cycles available to put bandaids all over all its failings. The deeper issue is the idea of statelessness... But that's another topic. Just let me overlay and we're good!

Comment: @RichardT - I assume you've discounted the idea of using a server-side language for this?