# How to make navbar constant across multiple pages?

Tags: php, html, css, navigation

I have looked at prevous questions about this and people say php and have not found an answer. how do I convert my navbar to php and use it in multiple html pages. Could someone tell me how to do so? I am currently taking a codecademy course on php and it is really hard for me to understand so please be patient.

```html
<div class="tabs">
  <ul>
    <a href="http://degraphic-design.dunked.com/contact-me" style="text-decoration:none">
      <li class="contact">Contact</li>
    </a>
    <li class="dropdown">Shop</li>
    <li class="forum">Forum</li>
    <a href="index.html" style="text-decoration:none">
      <li class="about">About</li>
    </a>
    <li class="team">Team</li>
    <a href="http://degraphic-design.dunked.com/" style="text-decoration:none">
      <li class="portfolio">Portfolio</li>
    </a>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: You could use [this](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_html_include.asp)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Creating reusable html for navigation bar on multiple pages](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4607136/creating-reusable-html-for-navigation-bar-on-multiple-pages)

Comment: You tagged this post `php` - how do previous recommendations to use php not answer your question? It's important to say *why* that doesn't answer your question, so we have an idea of the kind of answer that *will* answer your question. Do you need instructions on how or something?

Comment: You can always use jQuery's `$.load()` or another front-end framework. Or a static site builder like jekyll.

Comment: Just so you know, that HTML is invalid (syntactically) - the ONLY child to a `<ul>` or `<ol>` is `<li>` - you cannot wrap a `<li>` inside a `<a>`, nor is it the correct way to make (I assume) the entire `<li>` clickable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Say you have `about.php` and `home.php` in the root of your website. Create a directory called `partials` (or whatever), go into `partials` and put the contents of your navigation HTML in a file called `nav.php`. Then in `about.php` and `home.php`, use this where you want to include the navigation code

```
<?php include 'partials/nav.php'; ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way (extremly basic):

Create a PHP file called index.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<header>
    <?php
    include 'header.php';

    /**
     * say you wanted a different header for shop
     * if($_GET['page'] === 'shop') {
     *      include 'header-shop.php';
     * } else {
     *      include 'header.php';
     *}         
     */
    ?>
</header>
<div id="main">
    <?php
    include $_GET['page'].'.php'; // assuming your storing your pages in same path as index
    ?>
</div>
<footer>

    <?php
    include 'footer.php';
    ?>
</footer>
</body>
</html>
```

Then a header.php

```
<div class="tabs">
    <ul>
    <li><a href="index.php?page=contact">Contact</a></li>
    <li><a href="index.php?page=shop">Shop</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

And create your page files contact.php, shop.php ect.

Updated to a slightly more elaborate example to give you the idea.

Comment: Okay I have also heard that it is possible to just have a navbar.php and import that to each page
could you explain that?

Comment: You can do both. The way i show also gives you the benefit that you wont have to include that header in every page file but only the index.php. You can also wrap the parts into DIV containers as you need them.