# Clone an entire div container on another page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, cloning

I have a div container which holds several other divs and other content, which collectively, makes up my slideout sidenav menu.

I would like to call that entire div from another page. I have tried some suggested jquery methods, but so far, have had no luck.

This is a shortened version of what the section looks like...

```
<!--Opening div for menu container-->
<div id="menuContainer">

  <div>
    <div>
      <span class="menu">
        <a href="#" onclick="CollapsiblePanel_1.open();">SECTION TITLE
          <p class="subMenuOpenBtn">Open&nbsp; &#9660;</p>
        </a></span></div>
      <div id="CollapsiblePanel_1" class="CollapsiblePanel">
        <div class="tab">
          <div class="subMenu">
          <ul>
            <a href="#"><li>Option 1</li></a>
            <a href="#"><li>Option 2</li></a>
            <a href="#"><li>Option 3</li></a>
            <a href="#"><li>Option 4</li></a>
            <a href="#"><li>Option 5</li></a>
          </ul>
          <div class="subMenuCloseBtn">
            <span><a href="#" onclick="CollapsiblePanel_news.close();">Close&nbsp; &#9650;</a>
            </span>
         </div>
</div><!--Closing div for menu container-->
```

I want to save that entire bit of code on it's own page called 'SlideOutPage' (I'm not entirely sure if tat page should be saved in an html, php, or other type page)

Then... on my index.php page, I want to create a new div or 'container', and somehow call that section of code into it.

Comment: Maybe my answer to a similar question helps you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42639118/how-to-make-navbar-constant-across-multiple-pages/42639213#42639213

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Difference between various methods**

The best way to do it is using **PHP** because its a backend scripting language and wont be visible to visitor. If someone visits the webpage, it looks normal to him/her.

Through **JQuery**, it will be visible in source code. So, in some way visitor can know that its fetching the div from another file.

```
<!-- external file `menu.html`
Opening div for menu container-->
<div id="menuContainer">

  <div>
    <div>
      <span class="menu">
        <a href="#" onclick="CollapsiblePanel_1.open();">SECTION TITLE
          <p class="subMenuOpenBtn">Open&nbsp; &#9660;</p>
        </a></span></div>
      <div id="CollapsiblePanel_1" class="CollapsiblePanel">
        <div class="tab">
          <div class="subMenu">
          <ul>
            <a href="#"><li>Option 1</li></a>
            <a href="#"><li>Option 2</li></a>
            <a href="#"><li>Option 3</li></a>
            <a href="#"><li>Option 4</li></a>
            <a href="#"><li>Option 5</li></a>
          </ul>
          <div class="subMenuCloseBtn">
            <span><a href="#" onclick="CollapsiblePanel_news.close();">Close&nbsp; &#9650;</a>
            </span>
         </div>
</div><!--Closing div for menu container-->
```

**Through PHP**

`include 'menu.html';` or `require 'menu.html'`

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <?php include 'menu.html'; ?>
</div>
```

or,

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <?php require 'menu.html'; ?>
</div>
```

The file in which this code is called should be `.php`.

You can also use `include_once 'menu.html'` or `require_once 'menu.html'`. In this your file will be called only one time in a page. If there is another occurrence of same file, then it won't be included.

**Through JQuery**

```
<div id="wrapper"></div>
<script>
    $(function() {
        $("#wrapper").load("menu.html");
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

This is possible through Javascript/jQuery, yes. Save that into a new file, then use jQuery's [.load()](http://api.jquery.com/load/) function like so.

```
<div id="wrapper">
    Loading, please wait...
</div>
```

JS:

```
<script>
$(function() {
    $("#wrapper").load("myfile.html");
}
</script>
```

HOWEVER, I would suggest doing this with PHP instead. You can just include the file with a PHP [include](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php) or [require](http://php.net/manual/en/function.require.php) statement.

```
<?php
    include "myfile.php";
?>
```

Comment: Just a comment, but `include`/`require` aren't functions, so you don't need the parenthesis. `include "myfile.php";` is all you need ([PHP manual](http://php.net/include))

Comment: beautiful, i took them out, thanks. funny cause i even referred to them as "statements" already haha

Comment: So if I understand that correctly... in my case, the div on the index.php page would look like this...

<?php include "../SlideOutPage.php/menuContainer"; ?>

Or did I get that markup wrong?

Comment: The PHP include should just use the path to the file. Don't put anything in the file except the one div. `<?php include "path/to/magical/file.php"; ?>`

Comment: A PHP include will basically just paste all the file's contents in place onto the page for you, as if you typed out all the HTML right there, wherever you put the include. So it [probably] doesn't matter if you include them in the file or not. Conventionally, CSS and JavaScript are kept in other files for organizational purposes.

Comment: OK. Also... this div calls for some CSS and js. to look and function properly. 

Should I call those links and scripts within the 'magical' file.php, or should I call them on the destination (index.php)?

Comment: OK, I'm gonna give it a whirl. Thanks. Ill let ya know how it goes shortly.

Comment: No problem. Feel free to accept my answer if it helped.

Comment: Thanks Andrew. So far so good. Meaning, the 'content' of the div has imported. 

However... as I expected would happen, I lost the CS styling and js functions which apply to that content.

I have attempted to include them within the 'magical' file, as well as the destination file. Either or and both. But the scripts and styles are not affecting the imported content. :(

Comment: If you replace the `<?php ... ?>` snippet of code with just the HTML, does it still work?

Comment: Yes, if I simply insert the full html container in the index page, with the .js and styling applied to that page, all functions and looks appropriate.

Comment: In that case, something completely different is going wrong. I'd have to see your source code.

Comment: OK. If you would do that, that would be great. Can you Private chat with me?

Comment: I'm afraid private chat is not available on this website. I don't know if you have enough reputation to chat in the chatrooms either.

Comment: Andrew... unfortunately, I can't chat yet on here. :( 

Also... I toyed around with things and discovered that the problem with the styling and scripts applying to the content may be something unrelated to the 'importing' I am trying to do.

I tested it several ways. The content looks and functions nicely on my local machine (server), but when I upload all the files and folders to my cPanel... the styling and function falls apart.

Comment: Yes. Are you able to solve it now or would you still like me to help you? (I can very briefly provide my email if you want)

Comment: If you want to provide your email real quick, ill verify I got it on here if you can look at the code.

Comment: got it. ill email you now

Comment: Victory is ours!!

Comment: LOL. Yes! Thank you!