# How to make the nav bar in all your pages without having to rewrite the code in each page separately

Tags: javascript, html, css

I designed a home page with a nav bar to reach for all website pages and now I wanna make this nav bar available on all pages
So How can I do this without the need for re-designed this nav bar in all pages from the beginning

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4607136/creating-reusable-html-for-navigation-bar-on-multiple-pages

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Creating reusable html for navigation bar on multiple pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4607136/creating-reusable-html-for-navigation-bar-on-multiple-pages)

Answer (score 0):

If its a regular html , css , js website you could use insertAdjacentHtml method

First make a scripts.js file.

```js
var navbarItems = `<ul>
                     <li>Home</li>
                     <li>About</li>
                     <li>Contact</li> 
                   </ul>
`
document.body.insertAdjacentHTML("afterbegin", navbarItems);
```

and then in every html file where you want the navbar, import that script.js file using script tag

```html
 <body>
    
    
    <script src="src/script.js"></script>
  </body>
```